# Remote access to a Minecraft server over SSH

Tags: remote-management, minecraft, restricted-shell

I have a dedicated server running Ubuntu Server 18.04. I'm going to be hosting a Minecraft server for someone. What's the best way to restrict their read, write, and execute access to *only* the Minecraft server directory? They'll also need access to Java to run the server.

Comment: How would I get Java? I don't really want to make a full copy of it in the chroot.

Comment: Put everything in a docker container then or a VM, e.g. kvm.